# Using Count with Duplicate date and time

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, odbc

I have a table that has duplicate date and time, Some date has duplicate time but really want to count it as 1 using SQL query, the distinct is not working and also not sure how to do this any help ? The purpose is to calculate how much download for each register number for each day. eg 2018-01-08 has duplicate Starttime, and should be counted as 1.

My query is not doing that.

```
Select  StartDate, Starttime, count(*) AS TOTALDOWNLOAD, RegisterNumber 
FROM            `SAMPLE.csv`
WHERE        (MaintenanceFlightTime > 0)
group by StartDate,Starttime, RegisterNumber
```

```
RegisterNumber  StartDate   StartTime
    A         2017-11-27    19:22:17
    A         2017-11-27    19:45:39
    B         2017-11-29    14:09:30
    A         2017-11-28    21:51:38
    A         2017-11-30    17:09:34
    B         2017-12-01    15:19:35
    A         2017-12-01    19:31:42
    B         2017-12-02    14:59:28
    B         2017-12-03    17:38:39
    B         2017-12-03    19:09:19
    B         2017-12-04    10:16:24
    B         2017-12-04    13:43:37
    B         2017-12-05    06:37:22
    A         2017-12-05    10:24:37
    A         2017-12-05    14:40:19
    B         2017-12-05    19:44:06
    A         2017-12-06    08:26:55
    A         2017-12-06    06:30:38
    A         2017-12-06    11:35:41
    A         2018-01-08    06:40:52
    A         2018-01-08    06:40:52
    A         2018-01-08    06:40:52
    A         2018-01-08    06:40:52
    A         2018-01-08    06:40:52
    A         2018-01-08    06:40:52
    A         2018-01-08    06:40:52
    A         2018-01-08    06:40:52
```

Comment: the output is not the output of the query. Please provide your table schema also.

Comment: Which [DBMS product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Comment: This is a csv file connected to by ODBC in ssrs. I am just doing the query on the csv file.

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
    Select  RegisterNumber, 
            count(distinct StartDate || '-' || Starttime) AS TOTALDOWNLOAD
    FROM            `SAMPLE.csv`
    WHERE        (MaintenanceFlightTime > 0)
    GROUP BY RegisterNumber
```

Comment: I have updated my answer. Using concatenation instead

Comment: Thanks. It is giving this error Error in SELECT clause: expression near '|'.
Unable to parse query text.

Comment: I have changed it again. I dunno what RDBMS is used so it is hard to know whether the types will match

Comment: The csv is generated from postgresql application. I connected to it through ODBC.

Comment: It gives this error source odbctext driver syntax error (missing operator) in query  expression Count(distinct StartDate,Starttime)

Comment: I have modified the answer. Check now after the concatenation change

Comment: it is still giving the error  as error [42000] [Microsoft ODBC text Driver] Syntax error missing operator) in query expression Count (DIStinct StartDate II '-' II Starttime)

Answer (score 0):

You should only include in the `group by` the rows you want in the result set.  So, if you want to count days per `RegisterNumber`, you would use:

```
SELECT RegisterNumber, COUNT(DISTINCT StartDate)
FROM `SAMPLE.csv`
WHERE MaintenanceFlightTime > 0
GROUP BY RegisterNumber ;
```

If you want to count distinct combinations of the date and time, then some databases let you use `COUNT(DISTINCT)` with multiple arguments:

```
SELECT RegisterNumber, COUNT(DISTINCT StartDate, StartTime)
FROM `SAMPLE.csv`
WHERE MaintenanceFlightTime > 0
GROUP BY RegisterNumber ;
```

In others, you would need to use string concatenation or date/time functions to combine the values into a single column.  At the extreme, you can also use a subquery:

```
SELECT RegisterNumber, COUNT(*)
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT RegisterNumber, StartDate, StartTime
      FROM `SAMPLE.csv`
      WHERE MaintenanceFlightTime > 0
     ) s
GROUP BY RegisterNumber ;
```

Comment: when I used the second answer , it gives error  :  Error in SELECT clause: expression near ','.
Missing FROM clause.
Unable to parse query text.

Comment: when I used the last answer it gives output, but not correct. It is addingtotal of everything rather than for each day